# Can I render an image along the X axis - so it's completely flat? or not

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera

I'm an interior design student and wanted a section of what my room would look like from the side image, and was wondering if I could get a rendered section from completely the side (x-axis) or do I have to use the camera function and not get it completely to the side? ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChGX5.png)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Select the camera and click the camera tab of the *Properties Window*.

Then under lens change the type from perspective to orthographic and adjust the orthographic scale to fit your scene.

Now you can press <kbd>N</kbd>  to adjust the location and rotation.
These settings should get you where you want to be:

- Location: (10, 0, 0)
- Rotation: (90, 0, 90)

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between views by pressing 1, 3 or 7 on numpad for Front, Righ and Top views (hold ctrl for Back, Left and Bottom).

Press 5 to switch between orthographic and perspective views.

To align camera (active one) with current view press ctrl + alt + 0 on numpad.

If you don't have a numpad, you can mark "emulate numpad" option in preferences.